# Fixing IndexingError to clean the data

Tags: python, pandas, nan, data-cleaning

I'm trying to identify outliers in each housing type category, but encountering an issue. Whenever I run the code, I receive the following error: "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

```
grouped = df.groupby('Type')
q1 = grouped["price"].quantile(0.25)
q3 = grouped["price"].quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1

upper_bound = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
lower_bound = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)

outliers = df[(df["price"].reset_index(drop=True) > upper_bound[df["Type"]].reset_index(drop=True)) | (df["price"].reset_index(drop=True) < lower_bound[df["Type"].reset_index(drop=True)])]
print(outliers)
```

When I run this part of the code

```
(df["price"].reset_index(drop=True) > upper_bound[df["Type"]].reset_index(drop=True)).reset_index(drop = True)
```

I'm getting boolean Series, but when I put it in the df[] it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to compute `q1`/`q3`, this will maintain the original index:

```
q1 = grouped["price"].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.25))
q3 = grouped["price"].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))

iqr = q3 - q1

upper_bound = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
lower_bound = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)

outliers = df[df["price"].gt(upper_bound) | df["price"].lt(lower_bound)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then `reset_index` is not necessary:

```
outliers = df[(df["price"] > df["Type"].map(upper_bound)) | 
              (df["price"] < df["Type"].map(lower_bound))]
print(outliers)
```